# order of output in scipy.fftpack.fft2

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, fft, fftpack

I have three columns of data I read in, so that I have an 
N by 3 array; first two columns are `x` and `y`, spatial, and the third
is a value `delta`. I want to get the 2-dimensional Fast Fourier
Transform of this data so, having the N by 3 array `data` I do, having
imported `fftpack` from `scipy`,

`f = fftpack.fft2(data)`

I look at `f`. Which column in `f`, an N x 3 array, is the value of the transform,
and which columns are k_x and k_y ?

Comment: You need to pass in a 2D array of values on an equispaced grid, use the `x` and `y` for that only, not as inputs to the FFT.

Comment: @Jaime So how exactly would I do that with raw x and y? And what then does the output of fft2 look like?